# How to open/play a video using java(Netbeans IDE) in the default media player

Tags: java, netbeans, video-player

I am trying to make an application in **Netbeans IDE (Java)**which views videos. I don't want to create a media player to view the videos. I just want to use the default media player.*my default media player is Windows media player*.

Comment: *I searched and tried a lot but I am not able to open the video* - what did you find? why didn't it work?

Comment: You can use Runtime class and Process class to execute any cmd or terminal command. You give the command to open the file.

Comment: Since you "searched and tried a lot...", you really need to show your code, and the specific problem(s) you are facing. As it stands your question looks like a request for someone to simply write your code for you.

Comment: Yes @skomisa i am just a 12th grade student and i dont know how to specify my problems in the correct manner. If you could help me with the code to open a defalut media player in windows it would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: BackSlash .Even i dont know what i did. I'm sorry. I'm not experienced in java. I tried whatever i found relevent . But nothing worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for opening your videos using java but this will work only on ubuntu or may be some other linux.You can also check your OS and change the command. For Windows it is just absolute path of the filename.

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("xdg-open <path+yourfilename>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

for windows

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
           String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/k", "Start", "<path+yourfilename>"};
                Process p =  runtime.exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```